# Update row in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a table in ReactJS that is displaying data from a database using the map function.  It works like so:

```
 displayData(){
 return this.state.legoParts.map((legoPart) => (
  <tr key={legoPart.id} onClick={() => this.showForm(legoPart)}>
    <td>
    {legoPart.piece}
    </td>
    <td>
    {legoPart.type}
    </td>
  </tr>
   )
 )
}
```

However I want a form, using the same data as the table row, to appear when the row is clicked so that I can then use the form to update the data.  I honestly have no idea how to go about this- I'm not sure if I should put the form in the table and have it display when clicked or something else.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: you need to have state at your legoParts array say `editing` which default is false, when click invoke `this.showForm` update the state on clicked index on your `legoParts` array then change editing state for that index to `true`. Now on map change your logic with `legoPart.editing ? <Form /> : <renderTableRow>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need your app state to keep track of the part you're editing, and while you are rendering the table, decide whether to render a table row or the form based on that app state. I've put an example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/624p7zpzww